# Cmake: undefined reference to included methods

Tags: c++, testing, cmake, g++, googletest

I am learning to use cmake and I am trying to compile a simple set of tests using gtest for a very small project that I wrote.

my CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(circuit_sim)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  # Specify the commit you depend on and update it regularly.
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

add_executable(test Connector.cpp test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test gtest_main)
```

I got most of it from the googletest docs. I am trying to compile an executable that has a main() in test.cpp and relies on a Connector class in Connector.cpp and Connector.h. All files are in the same directory

when I run cmake . and then make I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o: in function `AllTests_CircuitTest_Test::TestBody()':
test.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `Connector::Connector()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `Connector::Connector()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `Connector::Connector(Connector*)'       
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `Connector::connect(Connector*)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `Connector::in(unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `Connector::out()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `Connector::get_out_conn()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `Connector::get_v()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make:86: test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:139: CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

It seems that cmake did not know to include Connector.cpp in the compilation even though I specified it in the CMakeLists.txt. What am I doing wrong?

Code for Connector.cpp, currently it doesn't do very much lol but it's a wip

```
#include "Connector.h"
#include "circuit_utils.h"

Connector::Connector(){
    this->v = 0;
    this->c = 0;
    this->out_conn = nullptr;
}

Connector::Connector(Connector* out_conn){
    this->v = 0;
    this->c = 0;
    this->out_conn = out_conn;
}

Connector* Connector::connect(Connector* out_conn){
    this->out_conn = out_conn;
    return this;
}

Connector* Connector::in(uint64_t v, uint64_t c){
    this->v = v;
    this->c = c;
    //this->out();
    return this;
}

Connector* Connector::out(){
    if(out_conn != nullptr)
        out_conn->in(v, c);
    return this;
}

uint64_t Connector::get_v() { return v; }
uint64_t Connector::get_c() { return c; }
Connector* Connector::get_out_conn() { return out_conn; }

std::string Connector::to_string() {
    std::string to_return = "";
    to_return += "-------------\n";
    to_return += "voltage: " + std::to_string(FROM_MICROS(((double)v))) + " volts\n";
    to_return += "current: " + std::to_string(FROM_MICROS(((double)c))) + " amps\n";
    to_return += "-------------\n";
    return to_return;
}
```

Code for test.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <unistd.h>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "Connector.h"
#include "circuit_utils.h"

using namespace std;

TEST (AllTests, CircuitTest) {
    Connector* power = new Connector();
    Connector* ground = new Connector(); 
    power->connect(new Connector(ground));
    power->in(TO_MICROS(3.3), TO_MICROS(3.3));

    Connector *cur_conn = power;
    while(cur_conn != nullptr){
        sleep(5);
        cur_conn->out();
        cur_conn = cur_conn->get_out_conn();
    }
    ASSERT_EQ(3.3, ground->get_v());
}
```

Comment: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)` seems odd. I say that because 2.6 is very old.  It was released in 2008.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it off of the tutorial that I was following, I am used to using just gnu make and I am learning cmake for the first time. I imagine it isn't causing the issue, but for good practice, what version would you recommend putting?

Comment: I googled FetchContent and it tells me that it first appeared in CMake in 3.11 so that likely is a good starting point.

Comment: Probably, you `Conntector.cpp` doesn't define given methods. Please, show the code (C++ one, preferably in form of [mcve]).

Comment: That was my guess as well as from the outside it does not appear to be a CMake issue.

Comment: I edited it to have the code for test.cpp and Connector.cpp. I was able to get it to compile using gnu make

Comment: Have you tried setting up the project in a different dir or inside a fresh dir? Perhaps there is an issue with the make project not realizing some dependency is out of date...

Comment: I have found the problem. You were right. What was happening was I was using wsl with visual studio code, and I changed the name of the cmakelists file using the wsl commandline but vs code did not update correctly. I am not sure why this happens. The workaround is to close and then reopen the folder in vs code and avoid renaming or moving files using the command line, but I'm not sure if there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need external class, you should put that class "library" in `target_link_libraries()`, so that the last line of your CMakeLists.txt will become

```
target_link_libraries(test connector gtest_main)
```

Also, in another CMakeLists.txt which is in the same directory as Connector.cpp, your should declare them as one library:

```
set(SOURCES Connector.cpp)
add_library(connector STATIC ${SOURCES})
```